# Django Add To cart Function with UNIQUE constraint failed

Tags: python, django

I have an add-to-cart function that throws an error when It is triggered. The function works if a user uses the admin account, but when a user has a normal account, it shows the below error.

Views.py

```
@login_required
def add_to_cart(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)
    order_item, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(
        item=item,
        user=request.user,
        ordered=False,
    )
    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        # check if the order item is in the order
        if order.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
            order_item.quantity += 1
            order_item.save()

            order.save()
            messages.success(request, "This item was updated to your cart.")
        else:
            messages.success(request, "This item was added to your cart.")
            order.items.add(order_item)
            order.save()
    else:
        ordered_date = timezone.now()
        order = Order.objects.get_or_create(id=item.id,
            user=request.user, ordered_date=ordered_date)
        order.items.add(order_item)
        order.save()
        messages.success(request, "This item was added to your cart.")
    return redirect("product", slug=slug)
```

Models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.FloatField()
    stored = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    item_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=15)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid1)
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("product", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
    
    def get_add_to_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("add-to-cart", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })
    
    def get_remove_from_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("remove_from_cart", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })
        
    def get_add_single_item_to_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("add_single_item_to_cart", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })
    
    def get_remove_single_item_from_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("remove_single_item_from_cart", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })
        

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} of {self.item.title}"
    
    def get_total_item_price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.item.price
    
    def get_final_price(self):
        return self.get_total_item_price()
    
    def get_quantity(self):
        return self.quantity
    
      
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    total_price = models.FloatField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
    
    def get_total(self):
        total = 0
        for order_item in self.items.all():
            total += order_item.get_final_price()
        return total
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        total = 0
        self.total_price = self.get_total()
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Error message:

IntegrityError at /add-to-cart/start-with-why/
UNIQUE constraint failed: ecommpage_order.id
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/add-to-cart/start-with-why/
Django Version: 3.1.7
Exception Type: IntegrityError Exception Value:  UNIQUE constraint failed: ecommpage_order.id

Answer (score 1):

You create an order with `id=item.id`, but that makes not much sense since the database normally dispatches the id. Especially since you set the id of the order, this means that it is likely that eventually the same id will be used.

You thus should remove

```
order = Order.objects.get_or_create(
    id=item.id,
    user=request.user,
    ordered_date=ordered_date
)
```

and simply create an `Order` and then add an item to that order:

```
order, __ = Order.objects.get_or_create(
    user=request.user,
    ordered_date=ordered_date
)
order.items.add(order_item)
```

The modeling also looks a bit odd. Normally the quantity is stored in the [*junction table* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table). You can do that in Django by specifying a [**`through=…`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through).

---

> **Note**: Django's [**`DateTimeField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField)
> has a [**`auto_now_add=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField.auto_now_add)
> to work with timestamps. This will automatically assign the current datetime
> when creating the object, and mark it as non-editable (`editable=False`), such
> that it does not appear in `ModelForm`s by default.

Comment: I did the code above and gave me this error message **<Order: admin>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.**

Comment: But you need to *create* the `Order`. You thus need to use `.get_or_create(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for the links. So I modified the code and it works, but for admin users only. When I try a normal account, it' gives me this error message **"<Order: testuser>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.**. This is the reason why I included the id of the item earlier.

Comment: @ian: the `admin` user has nothing to do with this. Likely this is only due to the admin user having an `Order` already, or does not have an border whereas the testuser has no/has an order. You likely got the database therefore in an invalid state. You should check the database and try to fix this inconsistency.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just have 1 question. I figured that the problem came from the save method in the Models.py. When I removed that method, the function is perfectly working, but, now I can't get the total price of the items. Is there a way to solve it. If I will re-add the Save method in the model, I will get this message **"<Order: testuser>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.**

Comment: @ian: you can not do that before saving the field. I would advise *not* to store the price in the order, but simply calculate it when necessary, for example with an [**`.annotate()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#annotate).